# Moving a Sprite using a Scene2d button

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

I am creating an Android Game using LibGdx. It is a platformer and the map is tiled based. To test the movements of the player I used Key inputs and the desktop version of the game works fine. I created some buttons in scene2d and added them as an actor to the scene so that the game has movement buttons when played on Android devices. The buttons work as "*System.out.print*" shows. **Problem is:** the buttons and the player are each created in a different class. I can't seem to modify the velocity (and so the movement) of the Player from the class that holds the buttons. For that I need to change the velocity and speed etc. to static, which gives me strange errors on an Android device (Player won't show, or disappears after a frame). I am not sure how to fix this and what is the actual cause of this error. Here is some of the code of the different Classes:

**Main Class (MyGdxGame)** only included one button as an example.

```
 public class MyGdxGame extends Game implements ApplicationListener {

 private Skin skin;
 private Stage stage;

@Override
public void create() {  
    setScreen(new Play());
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/defaultskin.json"));
    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


    //Button Right
    TextButton buttonRight = new TextButton("Right", skin, "default");

    buttonRight.setWidth(50f);
    buttonRight.setHeight(50f);
    buttonRight.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() /2 - 250f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - 200f);

    buttonRight.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Hold");
            return true;
        }
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.print("Released");
        }

    });


    stage.addActor(buttonRight);

}
```

**Play Class**

```
public class Play implements Screen {
     private TiledMap map;
     private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
     private OrthographicCamera camera;

private Player player;

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 0);
    camera.update();

    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();

    renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
    player.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
    renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) { 
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("data/jack2.png")), (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0));
    player.setPosition(2 * player.getCollisionLayer().getTileWidth(), 10 * player.getCollisionLayer().getTileHeight());

}
```

**Player Class**

```
public class Player extends Sprite implements InputProcessor{

// the movement velocity //
public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
public float speed = 60 * 2, gravity = 60 * 1.8f;
private boolean canJump;
private TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer;
private String blockedKey = "blocked";
public Player(Sprite sprite, TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer){
    super(sprite);
    this.collisionLayer = collisionLayer;
}

@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
    update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    super.draw(spriteBatch);

}
```

So the button has a working ClickListener, but I don't know how it can modify the players velocity. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have some way to access that player instance from the class containing the button. In my games I make a static World class which can be accessed from anywhere in the program. Through the world class I can access the player instance. That's just how I do it, you may find another way. You say your program has errors on android device when making certain parameters static? Do you mean it compiles but it just doesn't work the way you expect? If that's the case, there is probably just a bug in how you're modifying the position or velocity of the player.